# Unable to Execute an Oracle Package withinin Java program

Tags: java, oracle

I have been working an API to automate the execution of procedures which exist within a package however, no matter what I have tried it has run the program to completion however nothing has been done. I know this because the procedure functionality is to truncate a table and when I execute the procedure within the Oracle environment it works, however, every time I try to do the execution from the code it doesn't work.

```
     CallableStatement vc   =   con.prepareCall("{call custom.populate_q03and2.Q03and02_main(?, ?, ?)}");       
        vc.setInt  (1  ,   10);
        vc.setString  (  2  ,   "all");
        vc.setString (  3,  "sdsj" );
```

When this code runs successfully it is expected that the table is truncated and currently it isn't being done.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? Is there an `execute()` anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, it was after the post I realized I didn't copy that part, but I know that the connection is built between the program and the database.

Comment: However, the issue still exists.. so any help would be great. here is the finish code:                                                                                       vc.execute();